# Yarn cannot start AM on some nodes after update

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hortonworks-data-platform

I've got a problem after updating system to HDP 2.6.5. I have a cluster with three nodes and trying to start a simple application with python:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext 
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession, HiveContext 
sc = SparkContext() 
print sc.master
```

with command

```
/usr/bin/spark-submit \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --name 'test script' \
    /opt/test/youdmp/test/script.py
```

It says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnProtos$ResourceProtoOrBuilder.getMemory()I
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.ResourcePBImpl.getMemory(ResourcePBImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.verifyClusterResources(Client.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1585)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:906)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I can see such situation when application starts on either on one or another node. But the third node works.

And client deploy-mode says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test/youdmp/test/script.py", line 3, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext()
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 119, in __init__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 181, in _do_init
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 279, in _initialize_context
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1428, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 320, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.YarnProtos$ResourceProtoOrBuilder.getMemory()I
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.ResourcePBImpl.getMemory(ResourcePBImpl.java:61)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.verifyClusterResources(Client.scala:313)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What kind of mistake can it be? What should I fix?

Seems like Yarn can't start Application Master on some nodes, because some libs are different on the nodes. But I cannot find out which libs are, both nodes have similar libs

Answer (score 0):

There were some library conflicts in my case.
Fixing that we should add option `spark.driver.extraClassPath`.

In our case
`spark.driver.extraClassPath    /usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/hadoop-yarn-common.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/hadoop-yarn-api.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hive-server2-hive2/lib/hive-hcatalog-core.jar`